# How to use keycloak in a singlepage applicationn

Tags: java, single-page-application, freemarker, keycloak

Currently we are investigating if we can use keycloak as iam for our whole company. It should replace the current solution (which is a single page application) with keycloak.
This means: Currently we have the Login Form and the Register Form rendered on one page. 
The flow is the following: First you have to enter an email -> then you get a new slide depending on if this email exists or not -> this would be either Login or create account.

Since this is all rendered on one page we need to also render the register form within the login template of keycloak.

Would be possible BUT the problem we are facing right now is that we can access the Bean UrlBean (of keycloak) using ${url.registrationAction} inside of the freemarker template -> but this returns the form action link of login instead of registration..

Does anybody knows who to get on a login page the Form action Link of registration?

login.tpl

```
<form name="register" method="post" action="${url.registrationAction}" class="js-form-submit-btn-disable">
url.registrationAction returns LoginAction instead of registration action...
</form>
```